# Edit the text while parsing the xml file

Tags: python, xml

I am new to programming in python and i have been working on parsing an xml file.

I have used the xml parser and i am able to parse the file.

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('hi.xml')

root = tree.getroot()
count = 0
for changetexts in root.findall('log'):
    temp = changetexts.text
```

The changetexts.text returns the entire contents under the log tag which are actually date and time of modification and a comment containing what has been modified.

But the problem arises now: I need the top 10 lines of the file log. But i actually retreive all the contents of the log files(say around 2000 lines).

Can anyone suggest me the concept that i should use to access the top 10 lines of the log.
Code snippets will also be helpful.

NOTE: There are no tags in the log tag.

the view of the tag is like this:

```
<log>
date_1            time_1             comment_1
date_2            time_2             comment_2
date_3            time_3             comment_3

</log>
```

Comment: What do you mean "top ten"? Do you mean the _first ten lines_, or some other criteria?

Comment: actually its the first 10 lines. Sorry that i did not specify it clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `splitlines()`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('hi.xml')

root = tree.getroot()
count = 0
for changetexts in root.findall('log'):
    temp = changetexts.text
    lines =  temp.splitlines()
    tenlines = lines[0:10]
    print (len(tenlines)) # Should be 10, use tenlines variable as you wish !!
```